# Python script execution Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, variables

I am very new to python, i was calling a function in my code, which has a while loop in it , the code is given below. The problem is that the variable 'n' which is being updated in the last of loop, doesnt change its value properly, instead it gets value '0' . i have checked it by pdb debugger. i am unable to understand why it is happening. I am NEW TO PYTHON. Am i wronglyy relating it to C/C++?
This programm generates random key, and we have to proove that those random keys will repeat after sometimes
CODE:

```
    def answer(n, b):


    cyclenum = 0  #his counts no. of times loop executes

    desired_len = len(str(n))  
    listofnums = []

    while True:
        newnum = str(n)  
        if newnum in listofnums:
            print(cyclenum)
            break

    bla=newnum.split() #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    x5=int(bla[0])
    x4=[]
    while(x5>0):
        t=x5%10
        x4.append(t)    # in this para , the sole aim is to rearrange the 
        x5 = x5/10     # digits of the no. in descending order
        x3 = sorted(x4, key=int, reverse=True)
    x2=map(str,x3)
    x1=''.join(x2)        
    bla=x1.split()
    x=int(bla[0])  #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


    bla=newnum.split()
    y5=int(bla[0])
    y4=[]
    while(y5>0):
        t=y5%10
        y4.append(t)   #if 0 comes in start due to ascending order
        y5 = y5/10      # they are ignored
        y3 = sorted(y4, key=int)
    y2=map(str,y3)
    y1=''.join(y2)        
    bla=y1.split()
    y=int(bla[0])


    z = x - y

    newz=0
    if len(str(z)) != desired_len:
    newz = map(int, str(z))
    lendiff = desired_len - len(str(z))
    newz = list(newz)
    for i in range(0, lendiff):
        newz.insert(0, 0)                 #here ignored 0 are added
    cyclenum += 1                         #to keep the length constant
    listofnums.append(newnum)                
    n = newz


answer(n="210022",b=3)
```

**********************EDIT 1
sorry , the indentation error was a mistake

Comment: Your code has indentation error. In order for us to help you, you need to provide code in a proper formatting. On the other hand, the problem might be in the line `newz=0`, since you then assign `newz` to `n`.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if we knew what that code's supposed to do. Please give us a general overview, and add comments in the code itself that explain what each section is trying to achieve. I suspect that `bla=x1.split()` and `bla=y1.split()` aren't doing what you expect. BTW, you probably should be using `//` rather than `/`; it doesn't matter in Python 2, but it makes a big difference in Python 3.

Comment: @Bit  i think you get my problem, i am confused about using the global keyword

Comment: @PM2Ring  i will add comments in a new edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the following if statement evaluates to true when you execute it?

```
if len(str(z)) != desired_len:
```

That would explain why it stays at 0.

Comment: as you can see of first iteration, the expression will evaluate to false, even then 'n' is '0'